# How can I ping from the cisco switch to host on one vlan but not another vlan?

Tags: cisco-2960

I have 2960 with two vlans, voice(40), data(50). I have 2 laptops and a VOIP phone connected. I can ping the gateway ( a Fortigate 60D which is the DHCP server which is working properly) from both laptops, I can ping the phone IP from the switch and the Fortigate. However, I can not ping the two laptops from the switch or the firewall, nor can i ping from 1 laptop to the other. 
Vlan interface on the Fortigate which is the gateway:VLAN50 10.45.5.1

Cisco 2960 - VLAN 50- ip address 10.45.5.2 255.255.255.0
             VLAN 40- ip address 10.45.4.2 255.255.255.0

How is this possible?

Comment: Please include the switch configuration. When you type show ip interface brief, which vlan interface is up?  Most likely your switch has no default gateway.

Comment: Can you confirm that the laptops receiving the appropriate addresses default routes within their respective VLAN's?  This - plus the switch config (as Ron mentioned) - would help diagnose your issue.

Comment: Both vlans are up:Vlan40                 10.45.4.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up
Vlan50                 10.45.5.2       YES NVRAM  up                    up

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you could provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 1):

A missing default gateway on an IP endpoint can cause this.  Also, the source address of the ping can cause this.  If you just type `ping` and press enter you'll get options including the ability to source that packet off a particular interface.

Comment: cant load the config where it can be read easily.....i verified the vlans are up with the correct default routes. I do have a default-gateway. I did ping sourcing from a different interface on the switch with no success. As a test, i disconnected the switch from the firewall. loaded static addresses in both laptops and still cant ping either one from the other or the switch. however, i can load the laptops statically on the VOICE subnet and pings are successful....this is a new switch, with the 1st configuration on it.. .thinking about factory resetting and starting over.

Comment: msgulx00#ping 10.45.5.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.45.5.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/6/21 ms
msgulx00#ping 10.45.4.1

Type escape sequence to abort.
Sending 5, 100-byte ICMP Echos to 10.45.4.1, timeout is 2 seconds:
!!!!!
Success rate is 100 percent (5/5), round-trip min/avg/max = 1/5/11 ms
msgulx00#

Comment: the above comment is pinging the vlan gateways